# In a sense, is using sin as an activation function equivalent to using cos as an activation function?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

In the DNN structure, we may use different kinds of activation functions. We can use cos or sin, but in a sense, is using sin as an activation function equivalent to using cos as an activation function?

Comment: `sin` and `cos` are nearly the same, except their phase

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ok! Thanks!